# Robot framework - Should contain match with regex - does not contain match for pattern error

Tags: python, regex, robotframework

I have the following robot file with defined keyword to run any command on a linux machine. In this case, I am attempting to find the mount permissions on the volume. However the regex doesn't match.

```
${output}   run command   cmd=stat -c %a /volume1
Should Contain Match   ${output}   770
```

Logs display the below error:

```
20210722 13:58:20.184 - INFO - +---- START KW: Collections.Should Contain Match [ ${output} | 770 ]
20210722 13:58:20.185 - FAIL - [ 770
 ] does not contain match for pattern '770'.
```

Not sure what I am missing in this case. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified that your `run command` keyword is returning a list? My guess is that it's returning a string, but `should contain match` expects a list.

Comment: I tried displaying the type and it did display as list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using glob pattern:

```js
Should Contain Match   ${output}   glob=*770*
```

Using regex:

```js
Should Contain Match   ${output}   regexp=770
```

Glob mode is default, and needs to find a match that equals the entire string.